# Return random boolean and use to guide an "if" statement

Tags: java, random, boolean

I've been researching how to return a random boolean and then use that returned boolean to drive an "if" statement, but I can't figure out how to structure or what syntax to use.

```
    private Random random;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    determineHit();
    if (random = true) {
    //Perform true//
    }
    else {
        //Perform false//
    }

private boolean determineHit() {
    return random.nextBoolean();
        }
```

How can I get my determineHit method to return the boolean and then plug that back into the main body of the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
private Random random;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    boolean hitResult = determineHit();
    if (hitResult) {
        //Perform true//
    }
    else {
        //Perform false//
    }

private boolean determineHit() {
    return random.nextBoolean();
}
```

Since an `if ()` requires a boolean result, the `== true` is implied, no need to explicitly code it.

Just make sure that you have instantiated `random` before using it, in a constructor for example.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work - I'm just getting errors from the console?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you make sure that you initialise your random with `random = new Random();` at some point?

Comment: I used return Math.random() < 0.5; instead and now works perfectly. :)

Comment: Math.random() is a static method, so an object doesn't have to be initialised. You probably don't have the object `random` initialised, so you can't call it's methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (random.nextBoolean()) {
    //Perform true//
} else {
    //Perform false//
}
```